# .htaccess - redirect user to subdomain without changing address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect visitors who go to www.example.com to www.sub.example.com, however their address (url) bar should remain the same - www.example.com. Is it possible using .htaccess or some other method, please? I'm pretty new to this. Thanks!

Comment: How is `www.sub.example.com` defined in `httpd.conf` and can you enable `mod_proxy` in your server config?

Comment: My domain/hosting provider is very limited and I can't see the httpd.conf file, only know the ftp structure. Also, I do not have the option to enable mod_proxy

Comment: You can't do this without mod_proxy